# can't re-establish connection to remote server after server restart | #pythonScript

Tags: python, ssh, fabric

I am trying to Automate a unix based system. I have a python fabfile.py with the automation scripts, which first connects to a remote server and run the script. In between the script I have a command which calls for system reboot.
At this point of time, I am loosing connection with the remote server and not able to re-establish connection.

```
--fabfile.py

//Import 

env.hosts = ['uname@host_ip']

def test() :

//here we run the commands

//calls reboot

//remaining commands
```

Can I re-establish the connection after calling 'reboot' command so that I can execute remaining commands?

Comment: learn to format code in stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Theres something else at work then here, not fabric.

Fabric run everything procedurally, meaning; if you have a list of things to run fabric will run them in order and when there is no more work to be done, THEN it disconnects not before. If you're having connection drops check either YOUR connection, the servers, or the servers ssh configuration. As an example:

```
from fabric.api import run, task
from fabric.state import env

@task
def dev():
    """
    I REALLY like the environments done in a task and not global, its easier to override
    """
    env.hosts = ['10.99.0.2']
    env.user = 'vagrant'
    env.password = 'vagrant'
    env.key_filename = '~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key'

@task
def whoami():
    run('whoami')

@task
def echo(msg):
    run('echo "{}"'.format(msg))
```

Simple test:

```
$ fab dev whoami echo:'hello world'
[10.99.0.2] Executing task 'whoami'
[10.99.0.2] run: whoami
[10.99.0.2] out: vagrant
[10.99.0.2] out: 

[10.99.0.2] Executing task 'echo'
[10.99.0.2] run: echo hello world
[10.99.0.2] out: hello world
[10.99.0.2] out: 


Done.
Disconnecting from 10.99.0.2... done.
```

or without you can still run it like this since you never hardcoded it:

```
$ fab whoami echo:'hello world' -H 'vagrant@10.99.0.2','ubuntu@*****' --password vagrant -i ~/.ssh/*****.pem
```

notice that the `dev` task was not ran here. Output:

```
[vagrant@10.99.0.2] Executing task 'whoami'
[vagrant@10.99.0.2] run: whoami
[vagrant@10.99.0.2] out: vagrant
[vagrant@10.99.0.2] out: 

[ubuntu@*****] Executing task 'whoami'
[ubuntu@*****] run: whoami
[ubuntu@*****] out: ubuntu
[ubuntu@*****] out: 

[vagrant@10.99.0.2] Executing task 'echo'
[vagrant@10.99.0.2] run: echo "hello world"
[vagrant@10.99.0.2] out: hello world
[vagrant@10.99.0.2] out: 

[ubuntu@*****] Executing task 'echo'
[ubuntu@*****] run: echo "hello world"
[ubuntu@*****] out: hello world
[ubuntu@*****] out: 


Done.
Disconnecting from ubuntu@*****... done.
Disconnecting from vagrant@10.99.0.2... done.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `time.sleep(t)` (where `t` is time in seconds) to pause your script up until the point the machine you've rebooted is back up.

Comment: When reboot happens connect will be lost, so after wakeup. will the fabric re establish connection ?

Comment: @deepak Just try it out and see for yourself? If the reconnect doesn't happen automatically, extend your code to do it.

Comment: tried it out soon after i commented, found it works fine :)